# MySQL query variable not set on new session

Tags: mysql, variables

I have the following query I am running via MySQLWorkbench. The query should return the diff between the current and previous row of col2 in the table1. Every time I start a new database session and run the query, the diff column displays null, but when I run it a second time the diff values show up correctly. How do I get it to run correctly on the first run?

```
 select col1, col2 - @prev as diff , @prev:= col2  
   from table1
```

Comment: When using a session variable by default it will be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query to get the result.

```
 select col1
      , coalesce(col2 - @prev, 0) as diff 
      , @prev as previous
      , @prev := col2 as temp_prev  
   from table1
   join (select @prev := null) t;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Could u add some explanation as to what is going on with @prev in this query. I'd like to understand how the issue was solved.

Comment: In general any `value - NULL` is always `NULL` so that on first time of query execution all the rows returned NULL. But after that your @prev will have the last value of `col2`. So again when you execute without restarting the session `col2 - last_col2` which will again result wrong unless you have ordered values in that column.

Comment: In my query I just `set @prev = null` before proceeding and I have added coalesce to avoid null and show the result as 0. the `previous` in the row 1 will be null which we initialized in the join. Then we are using set to store the 1st rows `col2` in @prev as temp_prev. Note that if you place `previous` at the last which is next to `temp_prev` then the value will be same as `temp_prev` coz we just recently assigned @prev.